# Memory leaks from 2d array on heap

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, memory-leaks, crash, heap-memory

I'm having an issue with a lot of memory leaks from a class I've created. The assignment is requires creating a word search puzzle on the heap. I've created my destructor,  copy constructor and overload the assignment operator.

I think there must be something wrong with one of these functions, because the final check to ensure it is working is to create objects in a loop, to see if it fails and my function is crashing. I've tried different forms of the destructor and I've tried changing around the copy and assignment operator with no luck. Kind of at a loss, and the lack of warnings is really making it difficult to debug without a proper understanding of the heap.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Here are some functions that are working with the heap.

```
JumblePuzzle::~JumblePuzzle(){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        delete jumble[i];
    }
    delete jumble;

}

JumblePuzzle::JumblePuzzle(string word, string diff){
    int i = 0;
    toHide = word;
    difficulty = diff;
    jumble = buildArray();
    fillArray();
    hideWord();
}

JumblePuzzle::JumblePuzzle(JumblePuzzle& temp){
    size = temp.size;
    rowPos = temp.rowPos;
    colPos = temp.colPos;
    direction = temp.direction;
    toHide = temp.toHide;
    difficulty = temp.difficulty;
    jumble = temp.getJumble();
}

JumblePuzzle& JumblePuzzle::operator=(const JumblePuzzle& right){
    if (this != &right){
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
            delete jumble[i];
        }
        delete[] jumble;
        size = right.size;
        rowPos = right.rowPos;
        colPos = right.colPos;
        direction = right.direction;
        toHide = right.toHide;
        difficulty = right.difficulty;
        jumble = right.getJumble();
    }
    return *this;
}

charArrayPtr* JumblePuzzle::buildArray() const{
    charArrayPtr* array = new char*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        array[i] = new char[size];
    }
    return array;
}
```

Here's the line its failing on.

```
int loopLimit =20;
for (int i = 0; i < loopLimit; i++)
    JumblePuzzle jp("HIDDENWORD", "hard");
```

Thanks for any possible help!

EDIT:

Here is my .h file as well.

```
#ifndef JUMBLE_H_
#define JUMBLE_H_

#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
typedef char* charArrayPtr;


class BadJumbleException {
public:
    BadJumbleException(const string&);
    string& what();
private:
    string message;
};

class JumblePuzzle{
public:
    JumblePuzzle(string, string); //simple constructor
    JumblePuzzle(JumblePuzzle&); //copy constructor
    ~JumblePuzzle();            //deconstructor
    charArrayPtr* getJumble() const;
    JumblePuzzle& operator=(const JumblePuzzle&);

    //accessors
    int getSize();
    int getRowPos();
    int getColPos();
    char getDirection();

private:
    //attributes
    int size;
    int rowPos;
    int colPos;
    char direction;
    charArrayPtr* jumble;
    string toHide;
    string difficulty;

    void fillArray();
    void hideWord();
    char randomDirection();
    int randomNum(int);
    charArrayPtr* buildArray() const;
};
#endif
```

and my getJumble. It's used to get the actual word search created. Returned a copy rather than the pointer so it cant be modified.

```
charArrayPtr* JumblePuzzle::getJumble() const{

    charArrayPtr* tempJumble = new char*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        tempJumble[i] = new char[size];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            tempJumble[i][j] = jumble[i][j];
        }
    }

    return tempJumble;
}
```

Comment: I wonder what `size` is when `JumblePuzzle(string word, string diff)` is fired? Your `buildArray` seems to assume it has been set, but it isn't when called from that code path.

Comment: In the destructor, shouldn't `delete jumble;` be `delete[] jumble`?

Comment: Please post your JumblePuzzle class definition.  Problems with copy-assignment operators have a lot to do with what's inside the class.  In addition, what is "getJumble()"?

Comment: I posted my class definition and my getjumble function.

Comment: ok. So why are you not calling getJumble in your assignment operator?  Also, your copy constructor and assignment operator (when not using the copy/swap idiom) should be practically identical.  The only difference being the latter returning `*this`.  But for some reason both of these functions you've coded are vastly different.

Answer (score 0):

There is one major thing wrong with your code, and that is you failed to initialize the "size" member in the JumblePuzzle(string, string) constructor.

There are other things you should do:

1) Create a separate function to destroy the 2d array within the JumblePuzzle class.  You seem to be copying the same loops to do this in multiple places.  No need for that if you just call a function to do this work.

2) Your assignment and copy constructor are not exception safe.  If new[] throws an exception during the creation of the copy, then the original object has invalidated data.  In other words, you've destroyed the data, and when you want to create another 2d array, when new[] says "oops", you've destroyed your original data and can't get it back.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give your suggestions a try. It is an assignment and its due shortly (this was a last minute desperate cry for help). I'll let you know how it goes. I actually did initialize size. There were a few if statements that set size, but I took them out due to taking up a lot of space on the post. I'll put it back in for clarity sake though.